# How to create custom Image Marker for google map in flutter and us it inside custom widget?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, widget, google-maps-markers

How to use `custom widget` as market in `flutter google map` as to below image or how to achieve the below image as output in `flutter` ?

[image]

This is `my first time working with maps in flutter`. I know that I need to convert Image to `Unit8List` but that is the image only ! how to do it with images inside a custom widget ?

Images are from network api calls and the format is `base46` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working solution which I got after hours of testing is `masking` + `adding border` as per requirement to image on server side. as I was already able to convert the image to `BitmapDescriptor`. so simply it now I got the desired output.

Note: I was also able to convert the `base64` Image String to image and get it working in the mobile app. Issue is sometimes it displays and sometimes not. and as the quantity of the images increase, the issue too. so the above solutions is the best solution one can implement with practical simplicity.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `google_maps_flutter` package, you can create custom markers using your own images by using a `BitmapDescriptor` for your icon. First, you will need to define your assets/images on your `pubspec.yaml` under `flutter:` section:

```
flutter:
# To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
   - assets/images/
```

Then, define a `BitmapDescriptor` variable to store your icon on your `main.dart` before the map loads, like this:

```
 // Custom marker icon
 BitmapDescriptor icon;

 // List for storing markers
 List<Marker> allMarkers = [];

 @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(), 'assets/images/icon.png')
        .then((value) => icon = value);
 }
```

Lastly, you can add your marker with a custom icon on your `GoogleMap` widget under `onMapCreated` method using `setState`:

```
GoogleMap(
  initialCameraPosition: _initialLocation,
  mapType: MapType.normal,
  markers: Set.from(allMarkers),
  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
     
    setState(() {
       // add marker 
       allMarkers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('Google'),
          draggable: false,
          icon: icon,
          position: LatLng(37.422066,-122.08409)));
       });
    },
),
```

EDIT:

You can also load images from URL by using the [`http` package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) and then pass the response to `BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(bytes);`:

```
final Response response = await get("imageUrl");
icon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(response.bodyBytes);
```

Comment: the issue is that the image is over the network and I cam across the idea to send image as `base64` in api itself so that I don't need to wait for the image loading. current issue is that it takes some time for image to be processed so many times those Images are not displayed.

Comment: May I know how you are currently getting the image?

Comment: Have you tried using the [`http` package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) in getting the images from URL  then pass the bytes from the response to `BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes();` ? I edited my answer to include this

Comment: as I stated the issue is not that the image is not been fetched. its not been displayed is the issue. anyways I got the answer which is one of the alternative.

Comment: @jabamataro hi bro, is it can use dymanic image?